# Mongoose Query with $and, $or and then $and

Tags: mongoose

My query looks like this in Mongoose

```
matchRecord = await MatchRegister.findOne({
          $and: [
            { $or: [{$and:[{"Player1Name": slot1SaturdayArray[i]},{"Player2Name": slot1SaturdayArray[j]}]}],
                   [{$and:[{"Player1Name": slot1SaturdayArray[j]},{"Player2Name": slot1SaturdayArray[i]}]}]},
            { TournamentName: activeTournamentRecord.TournamentName},
            { MatchCompleted: {$eq: undefined}}
          ]
      }).exec()
```

But this keeps failing with this message

```
                   [{$and:[{"Player1Name": slot1SaturdayArray[j]},{"Player2Name": slot1SaturdayArray[i]}]}]},
                                                                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
```

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
select * from MatchRegister where TournamentName = 'gsm edition 6' and matchcompleted = 'yes' and (Player1Name='playername' and Player2Name='playername') or (Player1Name = 'playername' and player2name='playername')
```

Can someone guide me please. I have tried many other options, just pasting the most recent one I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked. I am sure yours is similar :)

```
matchRecord = await MatchRegister.findOne({
        $and: [{
          TournamentName: activeTournamentRecord.TournamentName
        }],
        $and: [{
          MatchCompleted: { $eq: undefined}
        }],
        $and: [{$or:[{$and: [{Player1Name: slot1SaturdayArray[i]},{Player2Name: slot1SaturdayArray[j]}]},
                     {$and: [{Player1Name: slot1SaturdayArray[j]},{Player2Name: slot1SaturdayArray[i]}]}
        ]}]
      }).exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an unexpected token.

```
matchRecord = await MatchRegister.findOne({
  $and: [{
      $or: [{
        $and: [{
          "Player1Name": slot1SaturdayArray[i]
        }, {
          "Player2Name": slot1SaturdayArray[j]
        }]
      },
      {
        $and: [{
          "Player1Name": slot1SaturdayArray[j]
        }, {
          "Player2Name": slot1SaturdayArray[i]
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      TournamentName: activeTournamentRecord.TournamentName
    },
    {
      MatchCompleted: {
        $eq: undefined
      }
    }
  ]
}).exec()
```

Try to indent the code in order to understand it while reading.

Comment: hey man are you sure this will solve the purpose. This had worked for me also earlier but look at the select problem I am trying to solve. Looking at the code it now looks like one and and then everything else is in the Or condition.

Comment: Plus this bombs because the query filter must not be an array so if you close with ']' immediately after {$eq:  undefined}. Mongoose takes it like an array being passed instead of a query filter and bombs. :(

Comment: On the first $or inside the primary $and you have and array for each one $and, so I removed the array closing bracket on the first $and and also the array opening bracket on the second $and, turning both $and part of the same single array.